# Compile and run a C file from another C program without using command line

Tags: c

I have two C programs:

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    system("gcc x.c -o x");
    system("x.exe");
    return 0;

}
```

x.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {


  printf("hello world!");

  return 0;
}
```

From `Main.c` I need to compile and run `x.c` without using the command line.  I've tried this but the code didn't work.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried this  `system("gcc x.c -o x && x.exe");` also ?

Comment: Please explain in detail what exactly you mean by "the code doesn't work". Quote errors, describe behaviour...

Comment: Did you try those commands directly in commandline? What happens then?

Comment: ok i fixed it, i should have run it from cygwin and not normal command prompt, thanks

Comment: Let's say that my x.c file is inside a folder which is not where Main.c is, how do i access it?i tried system("cd D:\\MAURI\\CS\\Example") but didn't work.

Comment: Does GCC automatically add `.exe` extension? Are the files located in your working directory where you execute that program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function call will compile your file and run it in one line :

```
system("gcc x.c -o x && x.exe");
```